# EHCache hangs when two instances of same app is running

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

Recently while testing my application which uses EHCache with disk persistence, I found that that the application hangs in the EHCache thread in case a second instance of the same  application is run.

I am guessing this could be because both the apps are trying to write to the same diskstore file.

However, I could not find any configuration in EHCachce using which I can give a different name to diskstore file every time the application is started.

Could you please let me know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace where the code is hanging?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem:
I was using the same name for the cahce everytime I create a cache .
Now I am using a timestamp along with the cache_name, this creates a different cache file with a different name for different instances of the same application. 
This solves the file locking issue.